# How to batch export raw data from Omniture (SiteCatalyst or Adobe Analytics)

Tags: bigdata, data-warehouse, adobe-analytics

I've been looking around but have been having difficulty finding how to batch export raw data reports from Adobe Site Catalyst.

I have a Servers report, with about 18,000 servers on it. Each of these servers have unique visitor data that I'm trying to access so that I can view the data across time in order to discern which sites should be shut down. The problem is, my access is limited.

When I am at the report page, and I click on the download, I only get the handful of results on the page. And on top of that, it aggregates the unique visitor data, so I can no longer see how it changes with time.

I can do each server individually by clicking on the server name in the report, and going to 'site metrics -> instances', and then downloading the data via the download button. However, I have over 18,000 sites. Crunching this all manually would take some time.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pull the data down into a form like this, with the date on the y axis, and the sever name on the x axis, and all the unique page hits as the data. 
[image: example here]

Even if I can't get it in the ideal format, is there any other way I can pull all of this data?

I'm new to Site Catalyst, is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, when you click on the **Download** link on the report, there's another **Advanced Download Options** link you can click. This will give you a popup for additional options, including increasing the number of rows to download, which is 50,000 rows maximum via this method (though the download may possibly fail from a browser request timeout depending on how many metrics you have included on the report...)

Alternatively, you can export data (no row limit) from **Data Warehouse**.  When you login to Adobe Analytics, at the top left is a triple-horizontal icon next to the "Adobe Marketing Cloud" logo. Click on that to toggle open the left-hand menu rail.  Navigate to **Analytics > Data Warehouse**.  If you do not see it there, then your contract with Adobe may not include it, or your login account may not have permissions to access it, or both.

Comment: I managed to find Data warehouse yesterday. However, my reports are failing to come through to my email due to file size. Any chance you know anyway to filter the breakdowns section anymore than whats provided in the interface? Thanks Crayon!

Comment: @TaylorTheDeveloper In **Data Warehouse** you can create segments if you want to filter the data.  But, not sure if you noticed, but for larger files there's an option to export it to an FTP location. At the bottom in **Schedule Delivery** section there's an **Advanced Delivery Options** link that gives you a popup with additional options. On the **Report Options** tab, at the bottom is a **Report Destination** section where you can select to deliver the report to an FTP location.  I'm not sure if there's an upper size limit but I've had files ~750mb delivered to me before..

Comment: I tried to create a segment, and from the segment manager panel it shows the filtering(server equals "servername") in the top right of the panel when I set it. However, when I go to Reports and Analytics and select the show segment option, it still included all of the other sites. The same thing is currently happening with Data Warehouse. I will be looking into the FTP as soon as it's possible, but currently I can't get access to an secure FTP server to put the data on within my organization. Thank you for your help, by the way.

Comment: @TaylorTheDeveloper one trick you can do as a short-term solution is setup an FTP import location within Adobe Analytics interface. Go to **Admin > Classification Importer > Import File > FTP Import**. Click the **Add New** button and you will get a popup.  It doesn't matter what data set or report suite you pick; just pick one and save. This will generate an FTP user/pass hosted by Adobe that you can send the file to.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Hey, I'm trying to use the Data Warehouse to download the whole Adobe Analytics table for a specific day, similar to the BigQuery export for GA 360. Is this possible? Is it possible to use SFTP? I don't see the option for FTP Import in the interface and get an error every time I try it. What a proper server name / port should look like? Thanks!